# How to test PARTIAL view was rendered in C# ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, view, partial-views

I have a view and it has partial view rendering inside:

```
<div class="partialViewDiv">
    @Html.RenderPartial("partial", Model.SomeModelProperty);
</div>
```

And a controller, which returns this view

```
public ActionResult Action()
        {
            ...
            var model = new SomeModel(){SomeModelProperty = "SomeValue"}
            return View("view", model);
        }
```

How to test view was rendered i know:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestView()
{
   ...
   var result = controller.Action();

   // Assert
   result.AssertViewRendered().ForView("view").WithViewData<SomeModel>();
}
```

but when I call

```
result.AssertPartialViewRendered().ForView("partial").WithViewData<SomeModelPropertyType>();
```

I get this error message

```
Expected result to be of type PartialViewResult. It is actually of type ViewResult.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're testing the controller: such tests essentially mock the view and just verify that the controller is returning the expected view (and model).

Because the View "view" that renders the PartialView "partial" is not involved in the testing, so you can't test whether it's doing what you expect.

In general, most people don't unit test Views; but if you want to do so look at [this blog](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html) or google for "MVC unit test view"

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
return View(model);
```

To

```
return PartialView(model);
```

Exception says it all. You are expecting a partial view result, but you are returning a view result.

Comment: The assertion `AssertPartialViewRendered().ForView("partial")...` will still fail as the controller is returning a view "view".