# Unit test view in MVC - Confirm partial view is executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm trying to assert that a particular partial view is rendered in a scenario like below.

```
@if (Model.IsLoggedIn)
{
   @Html.Partial("_LoggedIn")
}
else
{
   @Html.Partial("_NotLoggedIn")
}


var hc = new HomeController();

var actionResult = hc.Index(true);
```

Is there any way I can assert that a particular view name was rendered?

Thanks,
David

Comment: Maybe these two links can help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370532/how-to-test-partial-view-was-rendered-in-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc and http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html

Comment: I've already tried the MvcContrib test library, but i'm getting the same error as the FluentMVCTesting... Think I'll have t approach it in a different manor...

Comment: The second link suggests rendering a 'token' of some kind in the partial and searching for that in the rendered result. Porbably not the most elegant solution though.

Comment: yeah - i'd thought of that approach, but I don't want to pollute my views with data so I can specifically search for it in a unit test :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FluentMVCTesting](https://github.com/TestStack/TestStack.FluentMVCTesting) to assert the views that are rendered.

```
var hc = new HomeController();

hc.WithCallTo(c => c.Index(true))
    .ShouldRenderPartialView("_LoggedIn");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - I get the error "Expected action result to be a PartialViewResult, but instead received a ViewResult."

...because I'm getting a ViewResult back from the main call - not a partial view... 

I changed to use the "ShouldRenderView" method, but that failed as the actual view name rendered in "Index".

Comment: @DavidMcEleney you're right. I can't see a method that specifically addresses your scenario.